# View the existing ignore rules in Sentry

Tags: sentry

Sentry has the ability to setup a rule to ignore errors for a certain duration (1 day) or occurrence (< 10 times). I would like the ability to see these rules, is there a UI or programmatic way to access these? For example, here the Ui to create an ignore rule.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is visible in the Activity tab in the issue detail.

For example, ignoring an issue:
[image]

Or ignoring if happens N times:

[image]

Not sure there's a specific API to get this. That said, you can see what APIs the front end uses, and just call those.